# Disable a QDialogButtonBox button In a custom PySide6 QDialog

Tags: python-3.x, pyside6

My intent is to provide a dialog where the user can enter and return a name value (or an empty string if the dialog is cancelled).

I have a custom dialog which has a QDialogButtonBox and a QLineEdit.The button box has OK and Cancel buttons.  I would like to disable the OK button when the QLineEdit has an empty string.

This is my first posting, so please pardon me if there's an obvious solution

Here's part of my dialog:

```py
class TableNameDialog(QDialog, Ui_TableNameDialog):
    
    ...

    def exec(self):
        execResult = super().exec()
        if not execResult:
            return ""
        
        txt = self.tableNameLe.text()
        if len(txt) > 0:
            return txt
        else:
            return ""
```

And here's part of the dialog's UI in Qt Designer:

```py
class Ui_TableNameDialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, TableNameDialog):

        ...
        self.tableNameLe = QLineEdit(TableNameDialog)
        self.tableNameLe.setObjectName(u"tableNameLe")

        self.formLayout.setWidget(0, QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.tableNameLe)

        ...
        self.buttonBox = QDialogButtonBox(TableNameDialog)
        self.buttonBox.setObjectName(u"buttonBox")
        self.buttonBox.setEnabled(True)
        self.buttonBox.setOrientation(Qt.Horizontal)
        self.buttonBox.setStandardButtons(QDialogButtonBox.Cancel|QDialogButtonBox.Ok)
```

I'm darned if I know how to disable/enable the QDialogBox's OK button.

I've searched the QDialogButtonBox PySide6 docs but couldn't find anything pertinent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standard QDialogButtonBox buttons are accessible using the [`button()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qdialogbuttonbox.html#button) function along with their [`StandardButton`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qdialogbuttonbox.html#StandardButton-enum) enum.

You can therefore disable the <kbd>Ok</kbd> button depending on the contents of the line edit:

```py
class TableNameDialog(QDialog, Ui_TableNameDialog):

    ...

    def validate(self):
        self.buttonBox.button(QDialogButtonBox.Ok).setEnabled(
            bool(self.tableNameLe.text())
        )


    def exec(self):
        self.validate()
        self.tableNameLe.textEdited.connect(self.validate)

        if super().exec():
            return self.tableNameLe.text()
        return ''
```

Notes:

- you may want to *actually* validate the contents of the line edit; the simplest way is to use `str.strip()` in `validate()`, so that it will be considered acceptable as long as any non-space character has been entered;
- if you're going to return a string anyway, there's really no point in checking if the string length is greater than 0: if the string is empty, it would be `""` anyway (`return txt if len(txt) > 0 else ""` is exactly the same as `return txt`);
- if you plan to *reuse* the same instance, you should `disconnect` the `textEdited` signal before returning, otherwise it will be called as many times as `exec()` has been called on the same instance; alternatively use a `try/except` block that attempts to connect the signal with the `Qt.UniqueConnection` argument, or just connect it within the `__init__` of the class;

Comment: After that most helpful answer, I've got it to work properly, except in regard to reusing the same instance.  Could I have some code to drive the point home?

Comment: @SciFiReader What problem do you have with reusing the same instance?

Comment: It's more a case of not understanding the implications of single versus multiple instances.  If that's not too broad a question ...  BTW my time zone is +10 GMT

Comment: The implication is simple: a function/slot connected to a signal is called as many times as it's been connected to that signal. In my code I never disconnect from the `textEdited` signal, which is normally acceptable as long as you always use a new instanc of that dialog (which should also be destroyed as soon as it's closed, to avoid memory leaks). A simple demonstration of that is to add `print('validating')` to `validate()`, then create *one* instance of `TableNameDialog` and call it's `exec()` *twice* in a row. You'll see that the second time `validating` will be shown *twice* when typing.

Comment: Here's my final version:    def validate(self):
        txt = self.tableNameLe.text() 
        self.buttonBox.button(QDialogButtonBox.Ok).setEnabled(
            bool(txt.strip()) )
    
    def exec(self):
        self.validate()
        self.tableNameLe.textEdited.connect(self.validate)        
        if super().exec():
            return self.tableNameLe.text().strip()
        return ''

Comment: I don't understand, that code only adds text stripping, which is what I already suggested in my answer, while anything related to the reusability of the instance is identical. Do you understand what I wrote in my previous comment? Have you done the test I suggested?